# SQL Login Failed

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am making a website at work, the main website is linked to a backend SQL which I don't have access to. Up until yesterday everything was working fine for months. Then yesterday my system had some issues and we needed to perform a revert to a more stable point. 
and now my website is throwing this error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException

Exception: Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used
    with Windows authentication.
```

The main website works, But these are being thrown from the ASP controls we set up. 
I read over a few posts on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170927/login-failed-the-login-is-from-an-untrusted-domain-and-cannot-be-used-with-wind) and [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6fd9acaf-a2ae-4762-a04d-ea01b646bddb/error-systemdatasqlclientsqlexception-login-failed-the-login-is-from-an-untrusted-domain-and?forum=sqlsecurity) but I personally do not have access to that side database to switch the settings or connection strings. My manager thinks it's something with my user-profile settings but I can't see anything wrong, especially since it *was* working just fine before.

Is there anything I can do on my end to get the connection back to what is was before?

Comment: Yes, contact the administrator and request a password reset.

Comment: @BWS  i dont think that is the issue. He is trying to use windows Auth from an untrusted domain. He needs to either get on the domain that sql server is on, or get his domain to be trusted.

Answer (score 0):

The "untrusted domain" part of the error message has me curious. Are you using integrated authentication to the web server? Are you doing impersonation as well and using the user's credentials to connect to SQL? If so it could be a matter of needing to set up the SQL server to trust delegation from the web server. A system replacement on the SQL server without setting up the delegation again could explain this.  In that case, your windows admin would need to set up the proper trust relationship for delegated credentials.